# Spring JPA query for getting similar lists that are similar to a given list

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a class named `Product`. Also it is linked to `product` database table. Database server is PostgreSQL. I am using Spring Boot and Hibernate.

```
public class Product{
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ElementCollection
    @Nullable
    private List<String> labels;
}
```

The `Product` class has `labels` field which represents the objects in the `product` photo. For example,

```
List<String> labels = ["apple", "table", "phone"]
```

My main purpose is that I want to write a SQL query that will get all products that has "similar labels".

What is "similar labels" for me?
For example, let `labels1` represents the labels of the `product1` and let `labels2` represents the labels of the `product2`.

```
List<String> labels1 = ["apple", "table", "phone"]
List<String> labels2 = ["apple"]
```

There is only 1 item which is "`apple"` that is same in the two lists. So `sameItemCounter` is equal to `1`.

The total distinct item list in two list is equal to,

```
distinctItemList = ["apple","table","phone"]
```

So, `distinctItemCounter` is equal to `3`.

If `100*sameItemCounter/distincItemCounter` is bigger than the 30 then , the two label lists are "similar labels".

So in this case, `100*sameItemCounter/distincItemCounter` is equals to `33,3` which is bigger than the `30`, then we can say `labels1` and `labels2` are "similar labels". So, relatively, we can say `product1` and `product2` are "similar products".

Although I can make this already with getting all products in the database than make all processes in Spring Boot(backend side), I want to make all this processes with a database query.

I want to an answer which is similar to this form:

```
public static final String GET_ALL_SIMILAR_PRODUCTS = "query??";

@Query(value = FIND_PROJECTS, nativeQuery = true)
public List<Product> getAllSimilarProducts(Product p); // need to return all "similar products" of p.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `String<List>` should be `List<String>`

Comment: Most likely a stored procedure is what you need here.

Comment: @EugenCovaci thanks I fixed the typo but I couldn't solve the main problem yet.

Comment: What is the data type of `labels` in the table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't create the table, Hibernate create automatically from the Product class definition. In the Product class, labels composed of String.